# Metrizability of quotient spaces of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $X$ a metric space and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$. Is the space $X/\mathord{\sim}$ metrizable? I think that the answer is no, but I could not arrive at a counterexample.

Comment: Look up the line with two origins, it isn't Hausdorff, but it's the quotient of a metrizable space.

Comment: The cone of $(0,1)$ is not first-countable at the apex, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590205/show-that-the-cone-of-the-open-interval-0-1-can-not-be-embedded-in-any-euclid/594042#594042

Comment: In view of the answers which show that the quotient need not be Hausdorff, the more natural question is whether the quotient topology is generated by a pseudo-metric (where $d(x,y)=0$ does not imply $x=y$). This question is answered by the comment of Stefan Hamcke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a standard flat torus and the equivalence relation declares two points to be equivalent if they lie on the same line with a (fixed) irrational slope, the quotient is clearly not metrizable.

Answer (score 7):

A very simple way in which the quotient can fail to be metrizable is if there are equivalence classes that are not closed. Take your original space to be $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\sim$ have as its equivalence classes $(0,1)$ and all singletons $\{x\}$ with $x\notin(0,1)$. In the quotient topology, you can not separate $(0,1)$ and $1$ by open sets and the quotient space fails to be Hausdorff.